# Getting date value based on description field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called actlog .I have  activity info for each particular case.
Now I need to get date for which the case transferred from one team to another.

Below is the example.
Here I need to get date when the case transferred from level 1 to level 2.
i.e , 2/11/2018

```
Case    Team    Date    Agent   Summary
123 Level 2     2/13/2018   Ravi    Working on the case
123 Level 2     2/12/2018   Ravi    Working on the case
123 Level 2     2/11/2018   Ravi    Transferred to L2 : Agent Ravi
123 Level 1 2/10/2018   Ram Working on the case
123 Level 1 2/10/2018   Ram Working on the case
123 Level 1 2/10/2018   Ram Working on the case
123 Level 1 2/10/2018   Ram Working on the case
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(team) over (partition by case order by date) as prev_team
      from t
     ) t
where prev_team <> team;
```

I prefer depending on the actual data.  You could also try relying on the `summary` and using `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where summary like 'Transferred to%';
```